# PayPal Unable to checkout: We’re sorry, but we weren’t able to add this card

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I've implemented Paypal Smart Payment buttons in wordpress woocommerce payment
Our customers having problem of checking out with their Debit/credit cards. They receive message after clicking proceed to checkout. The error message as: “We’re sorry, but we weren’t able to add this card. Try again later or add a different card.”

I have tried with my personal credit cards and also have asked a few others to try….and everyone got the same error.

There’s built-in logging system enabled in the extension
Unfortunately, the logs don’t contain any details regarding the errors.
I also try to find solution on paypal and woocommerce community but nothing work.

Any idea?

Comment: What information is in the logs re: the communication with PayPal to set up the order/checkout before the card is entered?

Comment: I am having the same issue, is the website in Australia by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

I found this scenario to work, however, it gives radio buttons that will display the related link (Paypal or Credit Card). The credit card input field requires CSS (in my opinion) as the entire field is in grayscale.

Woo/Sales/Settings/Payments/Paypal(Accept PayPal, Pay Later and alternative payment types.)

Enable 'Standard Payments'. I suggest putting 'Paypal' in the title field. I have put the following in the description field: All payments are securely processed through Paypal. Login with your Paypal account, OR use the credit card option with no account required.
Intent: capture.
Instant payment: require.
Checkout billing data: Use WC form, do not show address.
Create gateway for standard card button: uncheck.
Require final confirmation: check.

(I have Pay later enabled.)

Advanced Card Processing Tab -
Enable: check.
Title: Credit Card.
(I've chosen no 3D secure.)

[Paypal Radio Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rH68e.png)
[CC Radio Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Njrf.png)

I also have my Paypal account set to redirect to WC Order Received Thank You Page. I used the auto-connect in WC to connect my business Paypal account.

If you don't enable Advance Card Processing, the "button styling preview" options will display as per below, (better looking) but the credit card processing will not work. I'd say there is a bug with the Smart Button set up on Paypal's end.

[Paypal's Smart Buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gOEP.png)

Hope this helps.